# Free faces in $M_\kappa$ polyhedral complexes.

Tags: group-theory, geometry, metric-spaces, simplicial-complex, metric-geometry

I am reading Bridson and Haefliger's ``Metric Spaces of Non-Positive Curvature" and I am struggling with Definition 5.9 of a *free face*.

> Let $K$ be an $M_\kappa$-polyhedral complex.  A closed $n$-cell $B$ in $K$ is said to be a *free face* if it is contained in the boundary of exactly one cell $B'$ of higher dimension and the intersection of $B'$ with some small neighborhood of an interior point of $B$ is connected.

My first question is, from this definition there does not appear to be a restriction on codimension, however, in the `usual' combinatorial definition, codimension 1 is required.

Secondly, in the following complex
[image: A simplicial complex.]

are all three edges ($a$, $b$ and $c$) free faces?

Finally, can you give an examples of non trivial contractible and non contractible simplicial complexes with no free faces?  (For the latter I think a  regular hollow tetrahedron works.)

Comment: Well, $B$ necessarily has codimension $1$ in $B'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all the edges in your example are free faces. In contrast, vertices are not free faces. I am not sure where did you find the "usual combinatorial definition", but if you consider the disjoint union of your example with a simplex of dimension 3 then edges are no longer of codimension 1 but they are still free.

[Dunce hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)) is a classical example of a contractible complex without free faces. It is only a Delta-complex not a simplicial complex. If this bothers you, just apply the barycentric subdivision twice. Another standard example is Bing's [house with two rooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_with_two_rooms).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted!